# Wpf Material Design Card Change Opacity In Code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I'm creating a material card like below in Xaml.

```
<materialDesign:Card x:Name="CardMainHouseKeeping" Width="112" Height="112" >
    <materialDesign:Card.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF2ECC71" Direction="266" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="15" Opacity="0.0"/>
    </materialDesign:Card.Effect>
    <Button x:Name="ButtonMainHouseKeeping" Width="112" Height="112" Click="ButtonMainHouseKeepingOnClicked">
    </Button>
</materialDesign:Card>
```

When the button is clicked, I want to change the Opacity of DropShadowEffect with code.

```
private void ButtonMainHouseKeepingOnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DoubleAnimation animateOpacity = new DoubleAnimation {
        From = 0,
        To = 0.8,
        Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400))
    };


    CardMainHouseKeeping.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty, animateOpacity);
}
```

But it doesn't work.What should I do?

Comment: Try CardMainHouseKeeping.Effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.OpacityProperty, animateOpacity);